# Direct sum the kernel involving linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra

How to show that if $f^2=id_v$, then $V=$ker$(f-id_v)\bigoplus$ker($f+id_v$)? Given that dim$_FV=n$ for some integer $n$ and $f$ is a linear operator.

We know that ker($f-id_v)\bigoplus$ker($f+id_v$)$\subseteq V$.

For showing $V \subseteq$ker$(f-id_v)\bigoplus$ker($f+id_v$)

I thought of getting a $v \in V$ such that I can express is as $v=r+s$ such that $r \in$ ker($f-id_v$) abd $s \in$ ker($f+id_v$).

And I can't make a way to write $v$ as such. Can I get some ideas how? Thanks.

Comment: Notice that $f$ needs to be an endomorphism of a vector space over a field of characteristic $\neq 2$.

Comment: The trick is to set $r = \frac12\left(v+f\left(v\right)\right)$ and $s = \frac12\left(v-f\left(v\right)\right)$. Do you see how it solves the problem?

Comment: Yes @darijgrinberg. That's actually how I express it. But does (1/2 + 1/2=1) defined on any field $F$?

Comment: $\frac12$ is defined when $F$ has characteristic $\neq 2$. When $F$ has characteristic $2$, the exercise is false to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
The minimal polynomial is $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$

Comment: Thanks @mcmat23. But I don't have yet any idea of minimal polynomial.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)

Comment: Not yet discussed in class.